# Some issues and odd error messages using net/http library in Ruby. What do the responses mean?

Tags: ruby

I have this code finally working:

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI('http://jobcoin.gemini.com/protozoan/api/transactions'), {})
=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
res.body
=> "{\"error\":{\"amount\":[\"This field is required\"],\"fromAddress\":[\"This field is required\"],\"toAddress\":[\"This field is required\"]}}"
```

I am able to make the post request to the server even though I have an error.

1. What does `readbody=true` mean?

This does not work. Why? What does the error message mean?

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI('http://www.jobcoin.gemini.com/protozoan/api/transactions'), {})
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

It seems like the `www` causes this to fail. Why is this? When I visit the site via a browser, the site does not exist. I always thought the two (with the www and without the `www`) were the same address. Is it not?

2. What does `nodename` or `socketerror` mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things here:

1. You are making an wrong request to an API, that's why you're getting
   the `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>`.
   According to the response body you're missing some required
   parameters.
2. The `SocketError` means you're trying to connect to a non-existing host.

Now to your questions:

1. `readbody=true` means the server response was read. Check `net/response.rb` line 197.
2. Think I've already answered some of your doubts with `SocketError`, `nodename` and `servname` refer to the domain name of the server.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What does it mean when the 'server response was read'? Does that mean the server received my request?

Comment: It means the server recieved your request, sent a response and the client processed it fully.

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: Read it in the code while answering your question, check the file and line I mentioned in my anwer.

Comment: Sorry, can you post the link? Did you mean here? https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http/response.rb

Comment: Right [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http/response.rb#L196)

Answer (score 1):

The message you get after executing `post_form` is coming from the [core ruby class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http/response.rb#L108) which represents the http response:

```
def inspect
  "#<#{self.class} #{@code} #{@message} readbody=#{@read}>"
end
```

This outputs the instance variable `@read` which(if I understand correctly) is a flag telling if the body was read.

The second question is too broad. In short words you can serve `www` or "naked domain" or both. Usually people redirect requests from `www` to the "naked domain" or visa-versa. In your case seems like the server doesn't serve `www` hence the error. The error message is pretty self-explanatory - "there is no node(computer) which serves this endpoint" - 
 [read about sockets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)

Comment: Oh I see... typically people redirect one to the other in regards to `www`.